# Looking for a way to optimize the way I'm reversing an object in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm saving a relationship to a pivot table that connects a helpdesk_ticket to a user_id with an extra column describing the last time they've viewed the ticket. I've found a solution but am looking for a way to optimize it because It seems a bit hacky.

The object I'm sending back is the saved relationship with the user relationship attached.

```
 $involved = HelpdeskTicketInvolved::where('helpdesk_ticket_id', $ticket_involved_user->helpdesk_ticket_id)->where('users_id', $ticket_involved_user->users_id)->with('user')->first();
```

As expected I get the following object back.

```
{
  "id": 27,
  "helpdesk_ticket_id": 1,
  "users_id": 20,
  "ticket_notifications": 1,
  "ticket_emails": 1,
  "created_at": "2017-06-26 10:13:00",
  "updated_at": "2017-06-26 10:13:00",
  "viewed_at": null
  "user": {
    "id": 20,
    "name": "Nate",
    "username": "nate",
    "email": "nate@email.com",
    "config": "",
    "ad_connected": true,
    "is_store": false,
    "force_reset": false,
    "disabled": false,
    "last_login": "2017-01-19 08:05:00",
    "created_at": "2016-10-04 18:15:00",
    "updated_at": "2017-05-31 12:00:00",
    "phone": null,
    "district_id": null,
    "deleted_at": null,
   }
}
```

I'd really like to reverse the order of the object so that I get the user back with a pivot of the saved relationship like I have below.

```
{
  "id": 20,
  "name": "Nate",
  "username": "nate",
  "email": "nate@email.com",
  "store_id": 89,
  "config": "",
  "ad_connected": true,
  "is_store": false,
  "force_reset": false,
  "disabled": false,
  "last_login": "2017-01-19 08:05:00",
  "created_at": "2016-10-04 18:15:00",
  "updated_at": "2017-05-31 12:00:00",
  "phone": null,
  "district_id": null,
  "deleted_at": null,
  "pivot": {
    "id": 27,
    "helpdesk_ticket_id": 1,
    "users_id": 20,
    "ticket_notifications": 1,
    "ticket_emails": 1,
    "created_at": "2017-06-26 10:13:00",
    "updated_at": "2017-06-26 10:13:00",
    "viewed_at": null
  }
}
```

So below is the code I'm working with now that works but I'm not happy with it. What's the best way to optimize this?

```
$involved = HelpdeskTicketInvolved::where('helpdesk_ticket_id', $ticket_involved_user->helpdesk_ticket_id)->where('users_id', $ticket_involved_user->users_id)->with('user')->first()->toArray();
        $return = $involved['user'];
        $return['pivot'] = $involved;
        unset($return['pivot']['user']);

        return Response::json($return, 200);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you might get what you need by doing:

```
User::with("helpdeskTicketInvolved")->find($userid); // Assuming you know the user id you want.
```

This assumes that in your user model you have:

```
public function helpdeskTicketInvolved() {
       return $this->hasMany(HelpdeskTicketInvolved::class)->withPivot(["ticket_notifications","ticket_emails"])->withTimestamps();
}
```

Comment: Are there any negatives to calling the User model from the Involved controller? Or is this a pretty standard use case?

Comment: Depends on how this is done. If e.g. the route is via user/{id}/involved/{iid} then it's standard. If not then maybe it's not that standard.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot.